# How to reduce any compound to non-compound type

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Requirement: Given the compound type 'T', what is the non-compound type used as a base type?

So far my attempt is this template alias:

```
template <class T>
using reduce_to_non_compound_t = 
    std::remove_all_extents_t< 
       std::remove_pointer_t< 
         std::remove_cvref_t < T > 
     > >;
```

for example

```
  // array of pointers to string
    using arr_of_sp = std::string * (&)[42];

  // should pass
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<
       std::string,
        reduce_to_non_compound_t<arr_of_sp>
   >  )
```

A number of use cases to test this is probably very large. Before I go any further with this, I would like to ask if anybody has any better idea or even implementation?

I am asking if such a thing is logical. This is where use cases are coming in. If it is logical then it can be written.

Comment: Does it mean that you want to remove all extents, references and pointers from a type?

Comment: What should the result be when there are multiple types in the compound type (like a function pointer)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes please

Comment: You will have to clarify a bit more on what you expect the type to be reduced to. What do you think `void() const` should become?

Comment: @PasserBy this is what I meant by "very large" number of use cases

Comment: *You* need to explain what you're asking, this is not a "use case".

Comment: @PasserBy I am asking if such a thing is logical. This is where use cases are coming in. If it is logical then it can be written.

Comment: Defining some reduce operation makes sense as long as it fits your needs, there needn't be much logic. If instead you have a specific problem you are trying to solve, that would help too.

Comment: @PasserBy, in general, you are right, in particular, please see the answer bellow made by Holy Black Cat. He understood what is the specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

If, as you say, you simply want to strip cv-qualifiers, pointers, references and extents from a type, then you can use this:

```
template <typename T, typename = void> struct base {using type = std::remove_cv_t<T>;};

template <typename T> using base_t = typename base<T>::type;

template <typename T> struct base<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>>
{using type = base_t<std::remove_all_extents_t<T>>;};

template <typename T> struct base<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference_v<T>>> 
{using type = base_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;};

template <typename T> struct base<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>>> 
{using type = base_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>;};
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, base_t<const int *volatile[4]>>);
```

It can be easily extended to work with member function pointers, functions, or something else.

Comment: Holy Cat! This might be it :)

Answer (score 0):

I might humbly report, my suggested (in the question) solution actually works.

Special thanks to Mr Holy Black Cat, who spotted a flaw, so I added 'dbj::remove_all_ptr_t`. Now solution now works for double, triple etc pointers too.

[Wandbox is here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/85QMeZNn81qbpqIQ)

```
    namespace dbj 
{
    template <typename T> struct remove_all_ptr { typedef T type;   };

    template <typename T> struct remove_all_ptr<T*> {
        using type = typename remove_all_ptr<std::remove_cv_t<T>>::type;
    };

    template <typename T>
    using remove_all_ptr_t = typename remove_all_ptr<T>::type ;

template< class T >
struct remove_cvref {
    typedef std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>> type;
};

template< class T >
using remove_cvref_t = typename remove_cvref<T>::type;

template <class T>
using to_base_t =
  remove_all_ptr_t< std::remove_all_extents_t< remove_cvref_t < T > > >;

} // dbj
```

Mr Holy Black Cat solution works too. Although some might find it a bit complicated (I personally think it is not).

My solution is in the namespace `dbj` and his is in a namespace `hbc`.  This is my quick test.

```
// testing
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::string, hbc::base_t<std::string * (&)[42]>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::string ,dbj::to_base_t<std::string * (&)[42]>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<void (), hbc::base_t<void ()>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void (), dbj::to_base_t<void ()>>);

// 
struct X { char data{}; char method () const { return {};} };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<X, hbc::base_t<X (&) []>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<X, dbj::to_base_t<X (&) []>>);

//
using method_t = char (X::*)() ;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<method_t, hbc::base_t< method_t (&) []>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<method_t, dbj::to_base_t< method_t (&) []>>);
```

Both solutions are passing the tests above. Wandbox [is here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/85QMeZNn81qbpqIQ).
Thank you all for the valuable discussion.

Comment: So you decided to not remove pointers? If you need to remove them, you'll have to use a recursive approach.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I see what you mean ... `dbj::to_base_t<char **>` will return `char *` and that is a failure.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, well I guess I just have to develop `dbj::remove_all_pointers<T>` and use it here ... Ok.